# Pegar o maior valor de uma lista?

Tags: c#

Preciso gerar 100 valores aleatórios, salvar numa lista (`List<>`) e pegar o maior número.

Como faço para pegar o maior número?

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque é tipo "faça meu trabalho de casa por mim"

Comment: Realmente aparenta ser isso @ThiagoLunardi, mas não é fora de escopo pois fala de programação. Talvez por ser muito aberta a opiniões.

Answer (score 3):

Você usará a função `Max()` [leia mais aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.110).aspx) exemplo:

```
List<int> lista = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int maiorValor = lista.Max();
Debug.WriteLine(maiorValor); //10
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando o Linq, basta chamar:

```
int maiorNumero = MinhaLista.Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando apenas C#:

```
// criar a lista
var lista = new long[100];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    // Cada segundo possui 10 milhoes de Ticks, 
    // isso ira gerar valores aleatorios para a lista
    lista[i] = DateTime.Now.Ticks; 

// corre a lista
long maiorValor = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    // se o valor atual da lista for maior que o valor que já tenho
    if(lista[i] > maioValor)
        // atualiza o valor que ja tenho
        maiorValor = lista[i];
```

Comment: Acho que poderia ser menos complicado, poderia usar a classe Random e depois utilizar as extensões LINQ para pegar o maior valor. Ambas são nativas ao C#.

Comment: Sim, certamente, todas as outras respostas foram assim. Mas é que estou interpretando que a pergunta foi feita por um super iniciante, que está aprendendo lógica de programação, e não apenas querendo usar c#, entende?

Comment: E linq é nativo ao NET framework.